# Sort file by key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning Python 3 and I'm having issues completing this task. It's given a file with a string on each new line. I have to sort its content by the string located between the first hyphen and the second hyphen and write the sorted content into a different file. This is what I tried so far, but nothing gets sorted:

```
def sort_keys(path, input, output):
list = []
with open(path+'\\'+input, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.count('-') >= 1:
            list.append(line)
sorted(list, key = lambda s: s.split("-")[1])
with open(path + "\\"+ output, 'w') as o:
    for line in list:
        o.write(line)

sort_keys("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop", "sample.txt", "results.txt")
```

This is the input file: https://pastebin.com/j8r8fZP6

- Question 1: What am I doing wrong with the sorting? I've used it to sort the words of a sentence on the last letter and it worked fine, but here don't know what I am doing wrong
- Question 2: I feel writing the content of the input file in a list, sorting the list and writing aftwerwards that content is not very efficient. What is the "pythonic" way of doing it?
- Question 3: Do you know any good exercises to learn working with files + folders in Python 3?

Kind regards

Comment: unrelated: dont  `.count()` use `if '-' in line:` ... count takes longer: `'------------------------------------------'`

Comment: dont use `list` as variable name - you shadow the build in.

Comment: fix your indentation - you'll get IndentationError with your current code

Comment: the indentation screwed up when I copied the code here. Thanks @ForceBru, working now

Comment: Use `os.path.join(path, output)`, not `path + "\\" + output`.

Comment: `sorted(list, key = lambda s: s.split("-")[1])` should be `list.sort(key = lambda s: s.split("-")[1])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sorting is fine. The problem is that sorted() *returns* a list, rather than altering the one provided. It's also much easier to use list comprehensions to read the file:

```
def sort_keys(path, infile, outfile):
    with open(path+'\\'+infile, 'r') as f:
        inputlines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if "-" in line]

    outputlines = sorted(inputlines, key=lambda s: s.split("-")[1])
    with open(path + "\\" + outfile, 'w') as o:
        for line in outputlines:
            o.write(line + "\n")


sort_keys("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop", "sample.txt", "results.txt")
```

I also changed a few variable names, for legibility's sake. 
EDIT: I understand that there are easier ways of doing the sorting (list.sort(x)), however this way seems more readable to me.

Answer (score 0):

First, your data has a couple lines without hyphens. Is that a typo? Or do you need to deal with those lines? If it is NOT a typo and those lines are supposed to be part of the data, how should they be handled?

I'm going to assume those lines are typos and ignore them for now.

Second, do you need to return the whole line? But each line is sorted by the 2nd group of characters between the hyphens? If that's the case...

first, read in the file:

```
f = open('./text.txt', 'r')
```

There are a couple ways to go from here, but let's clean up the file contents a little and make a list object:

```
l = [i.replace("\n","") for i in f]
```

This will create a list `l` with all the newline characters removed. This particular way of creating the list is called a list comprehension. You can do the exact same thing with the following code:

```
l = []
for i in f:
    l.append(i.replace("\n","")
```

Now lets create a dictionary with the key as the 2nd group and the value as the whole line. Again, there are some lines with no hyphens, so we are going to just skip those for now with a simple try/except block:

```
d = {}
for i in l:
    try:
        d[i.split("-")[1]] = i
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Now, here things can get slightly tricky. It depends on how you want to approach the problem. Dictionaries are inherently unsorted in python, so there is not a really good way to simply sort the dictionary. ONE way (not necessarily the BEST way) is to create a sorted list of the dictionary keys:

```
s = sorted([k for k, v in d.items()])
```

Again, I used a list comprehension here, but you can rewrite that line to do the exact same thing here:

```
s = []
for k, v in d.items():
    s.append(k)
s = sorted(s)
```

Now, we can write the dictionary back to a file by iterating through the dictionary using the sorted list. To see what I mean, lets print out the dictionary one value at a time using the sorted list as the keys:

```
for i in s:
    print(d[i])
```

But instead of printing, we will now append the line to a file:

```
o = open('./out.txt', 'a')
for i in s:
    o.write(d[i] + "\n")
```

Depending on your system and formatting, you may or may not need the `+ "\n"` part. Also note that you want to use `'a'` and not `'w'` because you are appending one line at a time and if you use `'w'` your file will only be the last item of the list.